# How to setup different Python interpreters on Sublime Text with SFTP and local?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I have a question regarding setting up different Python interpreters on sublime text when using SFTP on the remote server and the local one.

The thing is, I would like to use anaconda's autocomplete function in both local and remote environments, but these two environments have different settings. The local one is Python 3.6 whereas the remote one is Python3.7 with totally different packages. How should I set up the anaconda on Sublime Text to make it work? For example, when it's not on SFTP, use the local virtual environment, but when it comes to the remote server, use the remote virtual environment accordingly.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda doesn't work that way. It needs to actually run the Python executable locally. Even over an SSH connection, the local instance of the plugin can't talk to the remote Python. The only way you could do this is if you install Sublime on the remote server and connect from your local computer using a terminal server or remote XWindows session.